Squarespace analytics does not update
This has been going on for 4 days now. My Squarespace analytics only shows 7 or no views on certain days even when several people visit the site. I'm quite sure of this as I visited the site today through several different accounts and the analytics did not update. Can anyone help me?

Today's analytics after I visited the site several times ^

What do you mean by visit the site?  Maybe its checking for fraud and discounting your visits because they are not real.

When testing, have you clicked to opt-in to cookies and browsed more than the landing page?  Does your cookie policy have an opt-out option?
Just looked at a Squarespace site, and it (correctly) only sets both Google and Squarespace marketing cookies when you opt-in.
When you implement cookie policies that way, you tend to find a large amount of data is never recorded.
